# Scraping a.href returns blank value?

Tags: python-3.x, web-scraping, beautifulsoup

I'm trying to scrape some information from the following webpage https://smws.com/all-whisky?sort=pricedesc&page=1&per-page=128

The information I'm trying to scrape is the name of each item plus the product code (not quite there yet with the below code). For example, for the first item this would be "Goodnight and Joy" & "53.389". I then wish to iterate this over the whole webpage. My code is as follows:

```
import requests
import time
import smtplib
from email.message import EmailMessage
import hashlib
from urllib.request import urlopen
from datetime import datetime
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
from selenium import webdriver

url = 'https://smws.com/all-whisky?sort=pricedesc&page=1&per-page=128'

soup = BeautifulSoup(urlopen(url).read(),features="html.parser")

test = soup.find_all('a.href')

print(test)
```

However this simply returns

```
[]
```

Please could someone help me to return the information returned in a.href and potentially iterated for the entire page.

Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

please see the code below, its working good--

```
url = 'https://smws.com/all-whisky?sort=pricedesc&page=1&per-page=128'
r = requests.get(url)
soup = BeautifulSoup(r.content,features="html.parser")

for link in soup.find_all('a'):
   print(link.get('href'))
```

Answer (score 0):

The correct way to get the link [or `href` attributes] from every `a` tag is not `find_all('a.href')` as you have used it. You can instead do something like

```py
test = [s for s in soup.find_all('a') if s.get('href')]

#for just the links:
#test = [s.get('href') for s in soup.find_all('a') if s.get('href')]
```

and get the `a` tags that have `href` and are *available*  in the html you fetched.

I then printed with

```py
print(f'{len(test)} results:\n')
for t in test: print(f'[{t.get_text(strip=True)}]({t.get("href")})')
```

to [view both the text and the link](https://i.stack.imgur.com/FaneL.png) in each tag.

**However** that will still not get you the data you mentioned wanting

> the name of each item plus the product code

because that has not been loaded in the html you fetched (you can check with a `print(soup.text)`...and also, if you try `print(soup.find('ul', {"id":"product-listing-container"}).prettify())` you will [see](https://i.stack.imgur.com/2lu34.png) that `ul#product-listing-container` is filled with "skeleton products" instead of having the `article` tag filled with attributes [as on the page after products have loaded](https://i.stack.imgur.com/mkoDS.png)).

But I also noticed you have selenium in your imports, so it's easily resolved with that (you'll just have to have it confirm you're an adult and then wait for products to load and *then* use bs4 or just directly call selenium's `find_elements`...)

Comment: Where possible, paste text into the answer itself instead of links to images.

Comment: @MarkTolonen I worried about the output adding to what already felt like a long answer...I'll try to start pasting the text more often. Thanks for the feedback

Answer (score 0):

Information in that page is being hydrated via XHR calls, by javascript.
If you want to reach that information with Requests, you need to scrape the actual API endpoints. Here is one way to do it:

```
import requests
import pandas as pd

pd.set_option('display.max_columns', None)
pd.set_option('display.max_colwidth', None)

r = requests.get('https://api.smws.com/api/v1/bottles?store_id=uk&parent_id=61&page=1&sortBy=pricedesc&minPrice=0&maxPrice=0&perPage=128')
df = pd.json_normalize(r.json()['items'])
print(df)
```

Result printed in terminal:

```
id  sku name    url cask_no region  age abv cask_type   spirit_type list_description    price   stock   release_date    distilleddate   image   product_categories  categories
0   3072    004343GB0700631 Analytical allure   /analytical-allure/ 4.343   Highland    31.0    53.6%   2nd fill ex-madeira hogshead    Malt Whisky None    695.00  24  2022-10-19 13:00:00 1/5/1991    https://cdn11.bigcommerce.com/s-vagfena5nz/products/3072/images/4821/4.343-web__47052.1666104996.386.513.png?c=1    All Whisky/Flavour Profiles, All Whisky/Whisky by Region, All Whisky/Whisky by Age, All Whisky, All Whisky/Cask Type, All Whisky/Whisky/Outturn, All Whisky/Whisky, Whisky/Outturn/Mid-Month Releases, All Whisky/Whisky by Region/Highland, All Whisky/Whisky/Vaults Collection, All Whisky/Flavour Profiles/Lightly Peated, All Whisky/Whisky by Age/21+ Years, All Whisky/Cask Type/Other Fortified Wines & Wine Casks, All Whisky/Whisky/Spirit of the Season   [All Whisky/Flavour Profiles, All Whisky/Whisky by Region, All Whisky/Whisky by Age, All Whisky, All Whisky/Cask Type, All Whisky/Whisky/Outturn, All Whisky/Whisky, Whisky/Outturn/Mid-Month Releases, All Whisky/Whisky by Region/Highland, All Whisky/Whisky/Vaults Collection, All Whisky/Flavour Profiles/Lightly Peated, All Whisky/Whisky by Age/21+ Years, All Whisky/Cask Type/Other Fortified Wines & Wine Casks, All Whisky/Whisky/Spirit of the Season]
1   2826    053389GB0700630 Goodnight and joy   /goodnight-and-joy/ 53.389  Islay   30.0    55.5%   refill ex-sherry butt   Malt Whisky None    495.00  15  2022-07-25 08:00:00 21/6/1991   https://cdn11.bigcommerce.com/s-vagfena5nz/products/2826/images/4416/53.389-web__29542.1658745823.386.513.png?c=1   All Whisky/Whisky by Age/21+ Years, All Whisky/Flavour Profiles, All Whisky/Flavour Profiles/Peated, All Whisky/Whisky by Region, All Whisky/Whisky by Region/Islay, All Whisky/Whisky by Age, All Whisky, All Whisky/Single Cask Whisky, All Whisky/Whisky/Vaults Collection, All Whisky/Cask Type/Sherry Casks, No Menu Link/External Tastings, No Menu Link/External Tastings/Sept22 Tasting Bottles, All Whisky/Cask Type, All Whisky/Whisky/Last Drops [All Whisky/Whisky by Age/21+ Years, All Whisky/Flavour Profiles, All Whisky/Flavour Profiles/Peated, All Whisky/Whisky by Region, All Whisky/Whisky by Region/Islay, All Whisky/Whisky by Age, All Whisky, All Whisky/Single Cask Whisky, All Whisky/Whisky/Vaults Collection, All Whisky/Cask Type/Sherry Casks, No Menu Link/External Tastings, No Menu Link/External Tastings/Sept22 Tasting Bottles, All Whisky/Cask Type, All Whisky/Whisky/Last Drops]
2   1124    095039GB0700638 Indian summer in a Japanese garden  /indian-summer-in-a-japanese-garden/    95.39   Speyside    38.0    53.0%   Refill ex-sherry butt   Malt Whisky None    435.00  35  2021-06-17 13:00:00 15/1/1982   https://cdn11.bigcommerce.com/s-vagfena5nz/products/1124/images/1770/95.39-VC-box-web__23227.1623844189.386.513.png?c=1 All Whisky/Whisky by Region/Speyside, All Whisky/Whisky by Age/21+ Years, All Whisky/Flavour Profiles, All Whisky/Flavour Profiles/Old & Dignified, All Whisky/Whisky by Region, All Whisky/Whisky by Age, All Whisky, All Whisky/Single Cask Whisky, All Whisky/Whisky/Vaults Collection, All Whisky/Cask Type/Sherry Casks, All Whisky/Cask Type  [All Whisky/Whisky by Region/Speyside, All Whisky/Whisky by Age/21+ Years, All Whisky/Flavour Profiles, All Whisky/Flavour Profiles/Old & Dignified, All Whisky/Whisky by Region, All Whisky/Whisky by Age, All Whisky, All Whisky/Single Cask Whisky, All Whisky/Whisky/Vaults Collection, All Whisky/Cask Type/Sherry Casks, All Whisky/Cask Type]
3   2111    012064GB0700631 Oh-so-orange    /oh-so-orange/  12.64   Speyside    31.0    43.4%   2nd fill ex-bourbon barrel  Malt Whisky None    434.65  11  2022-02-11 09:00:00 7/5/1990    https://cdn11.bigcommerce.com/s-vagfena5nz/products/2111/images/3102/12.64-VC-box-hires__68013.1657010779.386.513.png?c=1   All Whisky/Whisky by Region/Speyside, All Whisky/Whisky by Age/21+ Years, Categories Removed, All Whisky/Flavour Profiles, All Whisky/Flavour Profiles/Sweet Fruity & Mellow, All Whisky/Whisky by Region, All Whisky/Whisky by Age, All Whisky, All Whisky/Single Cask Whisky, All Whisky/Whisky/Vaults Collection, All Whisky/Cask Type/Bourbon Casks, All Whisky/Cask Type, Last Drops, All Whisky/Whisky/Last Drops [All Whisky/Whisky by Region/Speyside, All Whisky/Whisky by Age/21+ Years, Categories Removed, All Whisky/Flavour Profiles, All Whisky/Flavour Profiles/Sweet Fruity & Mellow, All Whisky/Whisky by Region, All Whisky/Whisky by Age, All Whisky, All Whisky/Single Cask Whisky, All Whisky/Whisky/Vaults Collection, All Whisky/Cask Type/Bourbon Casks, All Whisky/Cask Type, Last Drops, All Whisky/Whisky/Last Drops]
4   2897    012062GB0700631 Heaven-sent /heaven-sent/   12.62   Speyside    31.0    57.9%   1st fill ex-Pedro Ximenes butt  Malt Whisky None    385.00  5   2022-08-22 11:00:00 7/9/1989    https://cdn11.bigcommerce.com/s-vagfena5nz/products/2897/images/4563/12.62-VC-box-web_1__60925.1660742340.386.513.png?c=1   All Whisky/Flavour Profiles, All Whisky/Flavour Profiles/Deep Rich & Dried Fruits, All Whisky/Whisky by Region, All Whisky/Whisky by Age, All Whisky, All Whisky/Whisky/Vaults Collection, All Whisky/Whisky by Region/Speyside, All Whisky/Whisky by Age/21+ Years, All Whisky/Cask Type/Sherry Casks, All Whisky/Cask Type, All Whisky/Whisky/Last Drops  [All Whisky/Flavour Profiles, All Whisky/Flavour Profiles/Deep Rich & Dried Fruits, All Whisky/Whisky by Region, All Whisky/Whisky by Age, All Whisky, All Whisky/Whisky/Vaults Collection, All Whisky/Whisky by Region/Speyside, All Whisky/Whisky by Age/21+ Years, All Whisky/Cask Type/Sherry Casks, All Whisky/Cask Type, All Whisky/Whisky/Last Drops]
... ... ... ... ... ... ... ... ... ... ... ... ... ... ... ... ... ... ...
94  2898    006058GB0700608 Red swirl lollipop in a sidecar /red-swirl-lollipop-in-a-sidecar/   6.58    Speyside    8.0 65.5%   2nd fill ex-bourbon barrel  Malt Whisky None    49.80   14  2022-08-19 08:00:00 18/9/2013   https://cdn11.bigcommerce.com/s-vagfena5nz/products/2898/images/4565/6.58-web__01010.1660745386.386.513.png?c=1 All Whisky/Flavour Profiles, All Whisky/Flavour Profiles/Spicy & Sweet, All Whisky/Whisky by Region, All Whisky/Whisky by Age, All Whisky, All Whisky/Single Cask Whisky, All Whisky/Whisky by Age/Under 12 Years, All Whisky/Whisky by Region/Speyside, All Whisky/Whisky/Whisky Best Buys, All Whisky/Cask Type/Bourbon Casks, All Whisky/Cask Type   [All Whisky/Flavour Profiles, All Whisky/Flavour Profiles/Spicy & Sweet, All Whisky/Whisky by Region, All Whisky/Whisky by Age, All Whisky, All Whisky/Single Cask Whisky, All Whisky/Whisky by Age/Under 12 Years, All Whisky/Whisky by Region/Speyside, All Whisky/Whisky/Whisky Best Buys, All Whisky/Cask Type/Bourbon Casks, All Whisky/Cask Type]
95  3025    GN6002GB0700601 Old timey sippin' gin!  /old-timey-sippin-gin/  GN6.2   Edinburgh   1.0 49.3%   1st fill ex-bourbon barrel  Malt Whisky None    45.75   48  2022-10-07 08:00:00 10/9/2020   https://cdn11.bigcommerce.com/s-vagfena5nz/products/3025/images/4741/GN6.2-web__93878.1664901852.386.513.png?c=1    All Whisky/Whisky by Age, All Whisky, All Whisky/Single Cask Whisky, All Whisky/Whisky by Age/Under 12 Years, All Whisky/Cask Type, All Whisky/Cask Type/Bourbon Casks, All Whisky/Spirits, All Whisky/Spirits/Gin, All Whisky/Whisky, All Whisky/Whisky/Outturn    [All Whisky/Whisky by Age, All Whisky, All Whisky/Single Cask Whisky, All Whisky/Whisky by Age/Under 12 Years, All Whisky/Cask Type, All Whisky/Cask Type/Bourbon Casks, All Whisky/Spirits, All Whisky/Spirits/Gin, All Whisky/Whisky, All Whisky/Whisky/Outturn]
96  942 048111GB0700607 Baking in the potting shed  /baking-in-the-potting-shed/    48.111  Speyside    9.0 61.8%   1st fill ex-bourbon barrel  None    None    45.60   24  2022-10-07 08:00:00 7/11/2011   https://cdn11.bigcommerce.com/s-vagfena5nz/products/942/images/1391/48.111-bc__44272.1617989677.386.513.png?c=1 All Whisky/Whisky by Age/Under 12 Years, All Whisky/Whisky by Region/Speyside, All Whisky/Flavour Profiles/Spicy & Sweet, All Whisky, All Whisky/Single Cask Whisky, All Whisky/Cask Type/Bourbon Casks, All Whisky/Cask Type, All Whisky/Flavour Profiles, All Whisky/Whisky by Region, All Whisky/Whisky by Age, All Whisky/Whisky, All Whisky/Whisky/Outturn [All Whisky/Whisky by Age/Under 12 Years, All Whisky/Whisky by Region/Speyside, All Whisky/Flavour Profiles/Spicy & Sweet, All Whisky, All Whisky/Single Cask Whisky, All Whisky/Cask Type/Bourbon Casks, All Whisky/Cask Type, All Whisky/Flavour Profiles, All Whisky/Whisky by Region, All Whisky/Whisky by Age, All Whisky/Whisky, All Whisky/Whisky/Outturn]
97  345 SM0001GX0700607 Lemon odyssey   /lemon-odyssey  SM0.1   Blended Malt    7.0 50.0%   1st & 2nd fill ex-bourbon barrels   Malt Whisky None    45.00   50  None    11/6/2012   https://cdn11.bigcommerce.com/s-vagfena5nz/products/345/images/3979/Lemon-Odyssey-web__34434.1651854289.386.513.png?c=1 All Whisky/Whisky by Age/Under 12 Years, All Whisky/Whisky/Whisky Highlights, All Whisky/Flavour Profiles, All Whisky/Whisky by Region, All Whisky/Whisky by Region/International, All Whisky/Whisky by Age, All Whisky, All Whisky/Single Cask Whisky  [All Whisky/Whisky by Age/Under 12 Years, All Whisky/Whisky/Whisky Highlights, All Whisky/Flavour Profiles, All Whisky/Whisky by Region, All Whisky/Whisky by Region/International, All Whisky/Whisky by Age, All Whisky, All Whisky/Single Cask Whisky]
98  2904    DISC-VMT-GATH22-GB  Christmas Selection Box /Gathering-Discovery-Pack-2022  None    None    NaN None    None    None    Pick up a perfect present for the whisky lover in your life or get in the seasonal spirit yourself – either with a spot of self-exploration or by tuning into our online tasting, where our ambassador will guide you through the selection.    30.00   107 2022-08-22 08:00    None    https://cdn11.bigcommerce.com/s-vagfena5nz/products/2904/images/4578/TP_May_2020_Festival_01s__44827.1662024217.386.513.jpg?c=1 All Whisky/Whisky/Whisky Best Buys, All Whisky/Whisky/Outturn, All Whisky/Flavour Profiles, All Whisky/Whisky by Region, All Whisky/Whisky by Age, All Whisky, All Whisky/Whisky/Cases & Tasting Packs, All Whisky/Whisky/Whisky Gifts for all Occasions, All Whisky/Whisky/Spirit of the Season    [All Whisky/Whisky/Whisky Best Buys, All Whisky/Whisky/Outturn, All Whisky/Flavour Profiles, All Whisky/Whisky by Region, All Whisky/Whisky by Age, All Whisky, All Whisky/Whisky/Cases & Tasting Packs, All Whisky/Whisky/Whisky Gifts for all Occasions, All Whisky/Whisky/Spirit of the Season]
99 rows × 18 columns
```

​

See pandas documentation here: https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/

Also, Requests documentation: https://requests.readthedocs.io/en/latest/